# How to Add New Row in an Existing Table Using Novacode DocX

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

I have an existing table inside my Word Document which only consist headers. I want to add data on that table programmatically. I want to add rows in it but I can't find reference how to:

I tried the following:

```
Table myTable = document.Tables[0];
Row myRow = new Row();
myTable.Rows.Add(myRow);
myTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("Sample Data");
myTable.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Append("Sample Data");
```

This returns an error after building: `The type 'Novacode.Row' has no constructors defined`

Comment: I am not familiar with `Novacode`, but error message is very clear - there is no constructor for `Row` class, you can not use `new Row()`. Typically (because object inherit its parent) there should be `NewRow()` (or `AddRow()`, etc.) method of the parent. Check if `Table` class has such method and create row by using your `myTable`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Row myRow = myTable.InsertRow();
myRow.Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("Sample Data");
myRow.Cells[1].Paragraphs.First().Append("Sample Data");
myTable.Rows.Add(myRow);
```

Comment: This should really be accepted as the answer - I couldn't find this documented anywhere else